# Add customer attributes to Magento shopping cart rules

Tags: magento-1.9, module, attributes, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I have `customer attributes` added using a module and I need to add add them to `Promotions`, especially for `Shopping Cart Price Rules`. I found [this](https://www.peakcollective.com/magento-1-9-sales-rule-condition-customer-attribute/) tutorial, but looks like I'm doing something wrong, because it doesn't work (the attributes are not added). I also can't contact the author for help.
I don't have any experience in creating `modules`, so please bear with me.
What I did:

1. in app/etc/modules I put XYZ_AddPromoCA.xml with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <XYZ_AddPromoCA>
        <active>false</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        </XYZ_AddPromoCA>
    </modules>
</config>
```

2. in app/local I created the following directory structure
   [image]
3. in `XYZ/AddPromoCA/etc` I created `config.xml` containing the code

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <XYZ_AddPromoCA>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </XYZ_AddPromoCA>
        </modules>
        <global>
          <models>
                <xyz_addpromoca>
                    <class>XYZ_AddPromoCA_Model</class>
                </xyz_addpromoca>
            </models>
            <events>
                <salesrule_rule_condition_combine>
                    <observers>
                        <xyz_addpromoca_add_customer_to_salesrules_conditions>
                            <class>XYZ_AddPromoCA_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>updateSalesRulesConditionsForCustomerAttributes</method>
                        </xyz_addpromoca_add_customer_to_salesrules_conditions>
                    </observers>
                </salesrule_rule_condition_combine>            
            </events>
        </global>
    </config>
```

4. in `XYZ/AddPromoCA/Model` put an `Observer.php` containing the code

```
    <?php
    class XYZ_AddPromoCA_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer 
    {
        public function updateSalesRulesConditionsForCustomerAttributes(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
        {
            $customerCondition = Mage::getModel('company/rule_condition_customer');
            $customerAttributes = $customerCondition->loadAttributeOptions()->getAttributeOption();
            $attributes = array();
            foreach ($customerAttributes as $code=>$label) {
                $attributes[] = array('value'=>'company/rule_condition_customer|'.$code, 'label'=>$label);
            }
            $additional = $observer->getAdditional();
            $conditions = array(
                array('label'=>'Customer Attribute', 'value'=>$attributes)
            );
            $additional->setConditions($conditions);
            return $additional;
        }
    }
```

5. and finally in XYZ/AddPromoCA/Model/Rule/Condition i put a Customer.php having the code

```
<?php
    class XYZ_AddPromoCA_Model_Rule_Condition_Customer extends Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Abstract
    {
        /**
         * @return $this
         * These are customer attributes we want to use as condition rules for
         */
        public function loadAttributeOptions()
        {
            $attributes = array(
                'account_type' => 'Account Type',
                'allowed_units' => 'Allowed Units',
            );
            $this->setAttributeOption($attributes);
            return $this;
        }
        /**
         * Validate Customer Rule Condition
         *
         * @param Varien_Object $object
         * @return bool
         */
        public function validate(Varien_Object $object)
        {
            $customer = ($object instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer) ? $object : $object->getQuote()->getCustomer();
            $customer
                ->setAccountType($customer->getAccountType())
                ->setAllowedUnits($customer->getAllowedUnits())
            return parent::validate($customer);
        }
    }
```

I am sure there's something wrong with calling the customer attribute and getting the values, because the attributes are created using a commercial extension and I don't know what part of the code to modify to call them.

The customer attribute codes and labels are
account_type / Account Type and
allowed_units / Allowed Units
The database tables created by the customer attributes extension are
[image]

If there's anyone who can help me to get this fixed, I'd really appreciate it.